# Merge multiple overleaf projects into a single project

Tags: overleaf

I had created multiple overleaf projects for different review versions of my paper and their response documents. Due to this, there are too many projects. Since they are for the same problem, I would like to merge them into a single project with subfolders. Is it possible to do this automatically or do I have to do this manually?

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf helpdesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Probably better to ask overleaf support directly. This is not really a latex related issue

Comment: Thanks. I'll contact them

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question should be asked to the Overleaf Help Desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)*

It's not really possible to merge projects online. In general, if you have multiple important versions of a document, you might prefer to [use the labels to mark important versions of your project](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_the_History_feature#Accessing_the_History_and_Labelled_Versions). This way you can keep all the versions within one project.

If you want to consolidate the projects now, the only feasible way is probably to download them as ZIP files, compile them into a single ZIP file as needed and upload this single ZIP file as a new project. Just one thing: If you want to use folders within this new project, bear in mind that unfortunately some features of Overleaf/LaTeX don't work well if the main file is in a subfolder.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Can you tell me or point me to a document which lists out what features won't work if the main file is in sub folder?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN That's a good question. Basically anything that relies on calls to external programs. This includes things like the indexes, glossaries, word count, xr package, TikZ externalization, minted, ...